# Passport information compromised

Tags: system-compromise

I still have my passport in hand but my purse was stolen with all my passport information and passwords with security questions and answers in it. Should I get a new passport or since I still have my passport am I safe

Answer (score 1):

I would report the theft to the police and highlight the point that your passport information was written down in it. Unsure of the laws where you are but in the UK if your passport has been stolen then you must report it. Obviously you still have your passport but with me not being a hardened criminal i am unsure if a passport can be recreated from the details you had written down.

Or ring the passport office, they will be able to advise.

Comment: reports have all been filed .. I have tried the passport office. They keep giving the different people who do not seem to know. Yes here in the US if it is stolen we must report it too. I just dont know about the other info. Thanks for your help . I'll keep trying to find out.

Answer (score 1):

If your passport is replaced, the only thing that will change is the passport number.  All the rest of the identifying information will necessarily be the same.  I've never seen a passport number, by itself and without the physical passport, used as identification.  (My experience is somewhat limited; I hope others will correct me if I'm wrong.)  So, even if the U.S. is willing to issue a new passport, I do not really see what it will accomplish.  The thieves already have everything that's given in your passport.

Instead of, or at least before, fretting about the passport, change all those passwords.  Use a password manager to generate random passwords.  (I like Password Safe because it *does not* have any kind of cloud sync capability.  Depending on how you run your life, that could be a drawback for you.)  If you must carry passwords with you, reduce the number to the bare minimum, or carry your password manager data on a flash drive.  (Be sure you have a backup.)  Even if the flash drive is stolen, it will (should) be protected by a strong password that you have memorized.

Consider a security freeze with each of the major credit bureaus.  Given a police report, you can probably do this without a fee.  No one else will be able to apply for credit in your name while the freeze is in effect.  (The downside is that *you* can't apply for credit, either.)